# Add a Drupal menu item with a hard coded path to a view that accepts arguments?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a view page that accepts a taxonomy term id as an argument at /foo/%bar. I want to add several menu items to the primary links in the form of /foo/actual-bar.

Whenever I try to do this I get the error message "The path '/foo/actual-bar' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."

How can I add such menu items?

Thanks,

Finbarr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head I believe there are a couple ways to do this:

1. Use absolute URLs (http://yoursite.com/foo/actual-bar) in the menu, which should bypass the check.
2. Define the links in a custom module using [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6)

It does seem to me that there should be a better way to achieve this, but these two options should at least get your going in the short term.

Comment: I didn't think to use an absolute URL, but you are absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to set the url in the view to **foo/%** it makes the argument required and the 6.x menu system will then see it as a valid URL.

However, just **/foo** will no longer be a valid URL, so you may need to create another page display in the view to accommodate the URL with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend set path in such way: /foo/%/bar
so you can access it via: /foo/actual/bar

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I have a custom module that defines a hook_menu but the menu UI won't allow me to enter it into the system.

Had to do the absolute path solution... though I sure don't like it!